# Simple way to keep Front-end Angular 5 and back-end Web API code separate?

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-2.0

I have developed an Angular 5 app with plenty of moving parts (Services, Bootstrap, Angular Material, internal+external JS scripts, etc). Now I want to add database connectivity to this app as well (MS SQL Server only). The app has been developed in Visual Studio Code.

I am following [this tutorial](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Angular-5-ASPNET-Core-CRUD-a7f382ab) from MSDN in order to learn how to connect this app with an SQL Server database. I believe I'll need Web API and .NET Core support for connectivity, and I can't find out a way to do that without starting from scratch in either of the VS Code (e.g. [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc)) or Visual Studio (like in the referenced article) since almost all the articles/tutorials I could find on the topic begin from scratch. The way I see it, creating a new Angular + Core project in Visual Studio and migrating the app logic there file-by-file is not a feasible solution for me.

My questions are:

- Is there a simple way to create a *separate* Web API-based back-end app which serves data from my SQL Server database for the front-end Angular 5 app to consume? Or would all the .NET Core, Web API, and Angular front-end support be rendered from the same app?
- If not, is there a simple/official way to add .NET Core and Web API functionality to an Angular 5 app built in VS Code?

Comment: Frequently developers build the Web API with Visual Studio as an entirely separate project from their Angular app built in VS Code.

Comment: @DeborahK - One of the reasons to ask this question was to confirm if I am even on the right track or not, since I have no .NET / Web API experience. I'll see if I can find some resources regarding it now. Thank you!

Comment: Please see this to create web api with visual studio code

Comment: This video might help you to get started https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/dotnet/Get-started-VSCode-Csharp-NET-Core-Windows

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I propose you to **create a separate project**  which contains the REST-Endpoint with ASP.NET Core.

Here you find a simple tutorial:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api

With this solution your server is decoupled from client. Maybe in future you like to use something other than angular or you like to create an other client (for example a native mobile app). In this case you do not have to change your server project.

(In the case you are working with visual studio take a look to the projecttemplate. There is every thing you need.

Answer (score 10):

Rendering Angular and ASP.NET Core from the same app would be beneficial if you need to render Angular app at server side (using Angular Universal). Otherwise you can create a separate **ASP.NET Core** or conventional **ASP.NET Web API** project as a back-end to fetch data from SQL Server and serve to the Angular client.

Comment: So if I create a separate ASP.NET Web API project for serving data from SQL Server database, what kind of additions to my Angular 5 app would be required to fetch them? (I just want a general idea regarding complexity, not a complete solution, e.g. would a `http.get()` call work for fetching records or a more complex technique would be required?)

Comment: Yes you'll only required to make http calls using HttpClient in Angular. Moreover you'll also need to enable CORS in your ASP.NET project so that your separate client app (on a different URL) can communicate with the server (on a different URL).

Answer (score 6):

I works fine for my projects. Give it a try.

Create two separate projects. Angular5 & Asp.net Core WebApi

Host static angular5 app in Kestrel web server

**1.** Publish Angular5 (https://angular.io/guide/deployment) Package contains `index.html` file

**2.** Add to `Configure` method in `startup.cs` file in WebAPI project
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();
```

**3.** Copy all published Angular5 files to folder `wwwroot` in WebAPI

**4.** Run WebAPI project will start Angular5 app by default.

p/s Config BaseURL in the client side to call server correctly

Answer (score 5):

This is a problem all Visual-Studio users face at some point in our professional career, and what you're asking is something I hear a lot from people who are new to angular.

Because visual studio templates are so easy to use, many seem to get the that idea the backend and the frontend are one block. asp.net MVC for example, does a remarkably good job at hiding all the coupling logic away from you, and everything seems to magically just work.

I encourage you to move to  **visual studio code**, start a new project using angular CLI, when you get to the `HttpClient` parts, suddenly things will get much clearer for you.

Comment: I've bounced back and forth between VS Code + Visual Studio for angular a number of times. The focus definitely seems to be on VS Code for useful extensions like https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=infinity1207.angular2-switcher which lets you toggle between ts, css and html files for the same component which is a massive timesaver once you get used to the shortcuts. Also VS Code is getting much smarter with respect to understanding angular code and being able to check the presence of properties in your .ts file when you reference them from .html which again is huge.

Comment: I wish I knew the roadmap for both products with respect to what they're trying to support. Is Visual Studio going to catch up, or am I just missing the install of some vital extension. Wish I knew, but for now I'm focussing on VS Code for angular and Visual Studio for Web API as two completely separate projects.

Answer (score 2):

Set up your development environment

- .NET Core 2.0.0 SDK or later.
- Visual Studio Code
- Visual Studio Code C# extension

I would do two separate projects.

Q1. Yes you can create basic template of [WEB API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-vsc) using these commands in vscode

```
mkdir TodoApi
cd TodoApi
dotnet new webapi
```

Q2. Angular application only need api Endpoint to communicate to any back-end application.

You can install [angular cli](https://cli.angular.io/)

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

**Create a angular template using angular cli.**

```
ng new PROJECT-NAME
cd PROJECT-NAME
ng serve
```

Now you can just point your service endpoint to the service exposed by ur API. It will start to serve the data.

[get started with vs code using C# & .Net core](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/dotnet/Get-started-VSCode-Csharp-NET-Core-Windows)

*I haven't tried*

You can also try these two projects combining to a single work space and create a build task so the WEBAPI and angular can operate from a single vs code window.