# I'm having trouble setting up my angular netcore 2.1 webapplication properly in Godaddy

Tags: angular, web-deployment

I deployed my netcore 2.1 Angular application using Visual Studio FTP profile to Godaddy Host.

The contents of the deployment include:

```
ClientApp folder
wwwroot
appsettings.json
application.dlls
web.config
```

There is a dist folder in the ClientApp with the glyph-icons and index.html.

I'm fairly new to how the hosting servers initiate the web page, but i'm fairly certain the root public_html is looking for the index.html which it doesn't seem to be able to access.

I've tried to copy the contents from the dist folder to the public_html on the server and it launches the application seemingly fine, but then my data retrieval from the controller doesn't work, giving a 404 api path not found.

Comment: Welcome to SO. When you build an angular app, you will get an index.html file which is the base for your entire app. Not sure how Godaddy host works, but while hosting an angular app (as for SPAs in general) you usually need to provide your index.html both as your index (main html) file and also as an error file (so instead of returning the 404, the serve actually gives your app the opportunity to handle the navigated route).

Answer (score 0):

This typically is due to the dotnet portion not being rendered. Check this out [Deploy and host .net core 2.0 and angular 6 app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52955767/deploy-and-host-net-core-2-0-and-angular-6-app)

As well as https://www.google.com/amp/dotnetdetail.net/how-to-deploy-angular-6-and-asp-net-core-application-in-iis-8/amp/

This will show you how the file structure should look. Hope this helps.